# Updating aria-hidden attribute if menu is purely CSS driven

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

I have decided to try and make my websites more accessible to screen readers and other assistive technologies. At the moment I'm really focussing on my navigation. Because who wants to iterate through all the items on a menu if the item you really want is nested deep and near the end?

So the website I'm working on has an entirely CSS-based dropdown menu which I am augmenting with javascript to make it keyboard accessible and adding aria attributes to help screen readers.

**My question is**

Given that my existing menu is pure CSS, I want to know if I now need to augment my menus with javascript to update the aria-hidden attribute whenever a part of the menu becomes visible? Or is it enough to set it to aria-hidden="true" in the first instance and leave it that way just to indicate the default state to the screen reader?

It just doesn't sit well with me that anything that uses pure CSS to show/hide content now needs to be augmented with javascript - it feels like it defeats the whole purpose of pure CSS display toggling.

Comment: Do you really need to use ARIA (except for `role="navigation"` landmark) if you're using correctly `display: none` (or `visibility: hidden`) in CSS and if it perfectly works with keyboard and mouse on an unordered list? A bunch of div and span would badly need ARIA, sure.

Comment: In this particular instance, I've opted not to use aria-hidden for this reason - although I've used all the correct roles throughout. Some people use it anyway, but I think the intent is to hide things from screen readers you're not hiding in the visual render. Screen readers SHOULD trivially be able to tell if something is visible or not through the DOM. If they didn't, I'd consider this buggy behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must set aria-hidden as its state changes.

> Authors MUST set aria-hidden="true" on content that is not displayed, regardless of the mechanism used to hide it.

[aria-hidden specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)

That wording suggests to me that whether you use CSS or javascript to toggle visibility, you need to update the aria-hidden value.

Comment: That is correct Iain. Aria-hidden='false' tells a screen reader that the contents within that element don't exist.

Comment: ARIA is great. However, screen readers do skip content that is hidden correctly with display:none; visibility: hidden;